# How can I calculate GKE PVC IOPS

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pvc

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance#machine-type-disk-limits

This document show performance with different vCPU VM types.
Where can I check this IOPS for PVC created by GKE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `PVC` in `GKE` using default `storageClass` you are using Google's Persistent Disks.

You can check estimated performance by following:

- `Cloud Console (Web UI) -> Compute Engine -> Disks -> DISK_NAME -> Estimated Performance`

---

Example:

Assuming that you created your `PVC` with a following manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pvc-standard
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 215Gi
```

You can check the associated `PV` to your `PVC` by:

- `$ kubectl get pvc pvc-standard`

The output should show:

```sh
NAME           STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc-standard   Bound    pv-volume-name                             215Gi      RWO            standard       4m16s
```

Please note the `pv-volume-name` as it will be the **part** of the name of your Persistent Disk.

Follow the steps below:

- `Cloud Console (Web UI) -> Compute Engine -> Disks -> DISK_NAME -> Estimated Performance`

You can see the estimated performance of your `PVC`:

[image: Persistent Disk IOPS]

> Tip!
>
> You can also check the `IOPS` when creating a Persistent Disk in `GCP`.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Persistent Disk](https://cloud.google.com/persistent-disk)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Compute: Docs: Disks: Pdspecs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdspecs)*

Comment: I don't see "Estimated performance". Do you know what can be the issue here?

Comment: @IvanAracki I think I've seen a thread on [Google's Issuetracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) a while ago.